# autonumber/rank by a column in access

Tags: rank, autonumber

I have a list of claim numbers and I want to add a ranking column that changes when there is a new claim number.

If the claim number is the same, I want the ranking to go up by 1, but when there is a new claim number, I want the ranking to start over

I tried this but it just inserted 1 for every line

please help

SELECT

Inst.[Encounter Control Number],((Select Count(*) 
from Inst 
Where [Encounter Control Number] = [Encounter Control Number];)+1) AS Rank

FROM Inst
order by  [Encounter Control Number] ;

Comment: You must remove the ; in your subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try similar to that:

```
SELECT Inst.[Encounter Control Number],((Select Count(*) from Inst I2 Where [Encounter Control Number] < I1.[Encounter Control Number])+1) AS Rank 
FROM Inst I1
order by [Encounter Control Number] ;
```

It will create a counter for each row.

Comment: thank you Frank, I get a dialogue box that asks me to enter a value for encounter control number.  but it is definitely a column in my table.  do you know how I can correct?

Comment: I'm doing this in access not sql if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

This will normally shown when access don't find the column. Is this not the name of your column? Please give me a screenshot of the table.